# Normalisation of the following wavefunction: $\psi(\theta,\phi)=\cos(\theta)$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction, normalization

Normalisation of the following wavefunction:

$\psi(\theta,\phi)=\cos(\theta)$

So I thought about setting the following

$N\int \cos(\theta)\cos^*(\theta) d\theta=1$

But then maybe I thought I was leaving out $\phi$ about using a volume integral like

$N\int^{2\pi}_{0} \int^{\pi}_{0}\int^{r}_{0} \cos(\theta) r^2drd\theta d\phi$

But my wavefunction has no $r$ dependence.

All help here is great. Apologies for obvious errors, I am new to quantum Mechanics

Comment: The way your wavefunction is written it is a function of $\theta$ and $\phi$.  I would assume that the system for which this is a wavefunction is defined on a two-dimensional space, the sphere of radius $1$.

Comment: There’s no reason to even think about $r$ or assume $r=1$. Just solve $\int |\psi(\theta, \phi)|^2| d\theta d\phi = 1$. That does however require that we assume something about the domains of integration.

Comment: You should check the form of dV for spherical coordinates. What you have is wrong.

Comment: @BillN I am missing a $\sin(\theta)$...I think

Comment: @innisfree would $\phi$ range from $0$ to $\pi$ and $\theta$ range from $0$ to $2\pi$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're given 
$$
\psi(\theta,\phi)=\cos\theta \tag{1}
$$
then you can't change it, you can't just multiply by more functions as you think it looks similar to volume integral of a sphere, because obviously they're completely 2 different things.

All you can do is multiply by a constant for normalisation so your initial intuition is correct.

For normalisation, you want the probability to equal 1 across the whole domain of the system, for which there is only a domain in $\theta$ and $\phi$.

For spherical coordinates, again you are correct in that the convention that 
$$
0\leq\theta\leq \pi \tag{2}
$$
$$
0\leq\phi\leq2\pi \tag{3}
$$
So to normalise across the entire space of your system:
$$
\int^{2\pi}_0\int^\pi_0|\psi(\theta,\phi)|^2 \sin\theta\;d\phi d\theta = 1 \tag{4}
$$
$\cos\theta$ is real so $(\cos{\theta})^* \equiv \cos\theta$
$$
N^2\int^{2\pi}_0\int^\pi_0 \cos^2\theta\sin\theta\; d\phi d\theta =1 \tag{5}
$$
$$
N^2\times \frac{4\pi}{3} = 1 \tag{6}
$$
$$
N = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{3}{\pi}} \tag{7}
$$

Comment: This is fine but be aware it is not the only choice that makes sense, nor the only one widely used in the literature, You could equally well normalize it using $\sin\theta d\theta d\phi$ and indeed this would be a good choice if the situation is in fact 3-dimensional and there is a function of $r$ involved somewhere too.

Comment: @AndrewSteane How can you normalise with respect to $\sin\theta$ which isn't a constant?

Comment: @andrew but surely in that case one should write it as $\psi(\cos \theta, \phi)$ to start with

Comment: @ZeroTheHero But we're not integrating over a volume here, that would specify that the wavefunction would change with respect to a radius, which it does not. We're integrating over the infinite space of angles as it were, over an infinite volume.
In your case, involving $\sin\theta$, $r\sin\theta$ is part of the $\phi$ angular part, you can't just miss off your $r$ coordinate because its not 'explicitly' angular. That way of normalising over a finite volume isn't the solution in this case. Perhaps it is fault of the question, (either as OP wrote it, or as he was given) that there is no R dep.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero The spherical harmonics are the angular part of solutions with an R dependence. This problem, has no R dependence.  By your logic, the wavelength doesn't exist, and can never exist in that form, $\psi(\theta,\phi) \neq \cos\theta$ as the integral of $\cos^2(x)\sin(x)$ over the limits is 0. If OP's problem is not just made up out of thin air, it must have a solution, one for which your rationale is incorrect.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Which bit do you have no idea? $\int^{2\pi}_0\int^{\pi}_0 \cos^2\theta\sin\theta\;d\phi d\theta = 0$ therefore your logic cannot be true. Because then the wave function exists no where. You're trying to apply the problem onto a sphere, of finite R where the problem doesn't exist on a finite sphere. The point stands that you're trying to argue based on $R,\theta,\phi$ dependence, which there is no R dependence.

Comment: But its a double integral, with respect to $d\theta$ and $d\phi$ where the integral == 0. And why are you limits $\pi$ to 0, not $2\pi$ to 0 for $\theta$.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero I do apologise, I've been mixed up between the maths and physics conventions. You are correct with your integral.

Comment: no worries.  It was pretty clear we were talking at cross-purposes.  This kind of bulletin board set-up is not ideal to resolve this kind of issues.  I will delete a bunch of upstream comments in the next 10 minutes or so as the confusion is now lifted.  I also just removed my downvote following your edit.